# How do I write multiple JSON dictionaries to a single JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to write eight JSON dictionaries each similar to the below-shown format into a single JSON file.

```
{
  "Category": {
    "0": "PCoIP Session Gateway (PSG)",
    "1": "Session Broker (PCM)",
    "2": "Web Access TURN Servers for PCoIP"
  },
  "Domain or IP address": {
    "0": "PCoIP Gateway Servers",
    "1": "Domains:  https://skylight-cm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.us-west-2.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm-fips.us-west-2.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com  https://skylight-cm-fips.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    "2": "Servers:  turn:*.us-east-1.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.us-west-2.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.ap-northeast-2.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.ap-southeast-1.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.ap-southeast-2.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.ap-northeast-1.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.ca-central-1.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.eu-central-1.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.eu-west-1.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.eu-west-2.rdn.amazonaws.com  turn:*.sa-east-1.rdn.amazonaws.com"
  }
}
```

This is my current code -

```
def export_to_json(df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list \
                       , df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list_for_pcoip \
                       , df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list_for_workSpaces_streaming_protocol_wsp_beta \
                       , df_health_check_servers \
                       , df_pcoip_gateway_servers \
                       , df_ip_ranges \
                       , df_wsp_beta_gateway_servers \
                       , df_management_interface_ip_ranges):
    
    dest_file_name = 'WORKSPACES_PORT_REQ_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.json'

    json_buffer = io.StringIO()

    # Adding dict to json file
    df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list.to_json(json_buffer)

    my_bucket.put_object(Key=dest_file_name, Body=json_buffer.getvalue())
```

This code currently adds one dictionary to the JSON file, how do I add all the other dictionaries (passed to this function as parameters) to the same JSON file.

Comment: store all the dictionaries in a list then convert to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the output file to be in the format `{...}` (contents of all files combined into one dictionary), or `[{...}, {...} ...]` (each file is a list element)?

Depending on your goal:

```
import json

# --- FORMAT: {...} --- #
result1 = {}

# your input dictionaries
for dct in dicts:
    # combine the dictionaries
    # if there are duplicate keys, the ones in 'dct' will overwrite those already in 'result'
    result1 = {**result1, **dct}

# write the output file
with open('result1.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result1 , outfile, indent=2) 


# --- FORMAT: [{...}, {...} ...] --- #
result2 = []

# your input dictionaries
for dct in dicts:
    # append the dictionary to the list
    result2.append(dct)

# write the output file
with open('result2.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result2, outfile, indent=2)
```

The above gives you two different output files depending on the intended format.

EDIT: To get your input dfs in a list, you can use `locals().keys()` in your function. So you can do something like `for df in locals().keys(): ...`

Putting it all together:

```
def export_to_json(df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list \
                       , df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list_for_pcoip \
                       , df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list_for_workSpaces_streaming_protocol_wsp_beta \
                       , df_health_check_servers \
                       , df_pcoip_gateway_servers \
                       , df_ip_ranges \
                       , df_wsp_beta_gateway_servers \
                       , df_management_interface_ip_ranges):
    
    dest_file_name = 'WORKSPACES_PORT_REQ_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.json'

    json_buffer = io.StringIO()

    result = {}
    dfs = locals().keys()
    
    for df in dfs:
        result = {**result, **df}

    # Adding dict to json file
    result.to_json(json_buffer)

    my_bucket.put_object(Key=dest_file_name, Body=json_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I'm trying to write the file to an AWS S3 bucket, `open()` does not work. Please see the code I'm currently using and suggest changes to it.

Comment: Isn't the `open()` part is equivalent to these 2 lines in your code?

```
    df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list.to_json(json_buffer)

    my_bucket.put_object(Key=dest_file_name, Body=json_buffer.getvalue())
```

So now instead of `df_domains_and_ip_addresses_to_add_to_your_allow_list.to_json(json_buffer)`, you do `result.to_json(json_buffer) ...`? You take the combined `result` dictionary and write it just like you did above

Comment: Thanks for checking I got this error `**base is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `**result` instead. Have made the edits